# Calling two functions sequentially in VBScript with single click event

Tags: vbscript

I need to call two functions on a single click event. and also the functions should get executed sequentially. I tried `<button onclick="copy();zip();"> click me </button>`. But it's not working. It's not calling any of the functions.

Here is the complete code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/vbscript">

function copy()
Dim WshShell, oExec,g,h
h="D:\d"

g="xcopy " & h & " " & "D:\y\ /E"
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set oExec = WshShell.Exec(g)

Do While oExec.Status = 0
     WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

WScript.Echo oExec.Status
end function

function zip()
Dim WshShel, oExe
Set WshShel = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set oExe = WshShel.Exec("cmd /c cd D:\d & D: & winzip32.exe -min -a D:\a")

Do While oExe.Status = 0
     WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

WScript.Echo oExe.Status
end function

</script>
</head>


<body>
<button onclick="copy();zip();"> click me </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a single function which calls `copy` and then `zip`. Wire that up to the `onclick` event.

Comment: function both()
call copy()
call zip()
end function
it only calls copy()

Comment: can u please tell the mistake i am making?

Comment: yes copying is erroring. but copy is giving the output. for the line:wscript.sleep=100 it says- object required:'wscript'